# Then can the all terms of sequence of the partial sums of the series be strictly greater than zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

It  is given that $\sum _{n=1} ^ \infty a_n = 0$  but $\sum _{n=1} ^ \infty |a_n| $  is not convergent .

Then can we get a series whose all the  terms of sequence of the partial sums of the series are strictly greater than zero?

I could not find an example.

Can anyone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the sequence of partial sums $A_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ as
$$ A_n = \left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n}&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\ \frac{1}{n^2} & \text{if }n\text{ is even}\end{array} \right.$$
then $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is implicitly defined and it fulfills the wanted constraints.

Comment: How can you prove the absolute divergence of the series?@Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: @cmi: by comparison with the harmonic series.

Answer (score 1):

If
$$
\begin{array}{l}
a_0=1\\
a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor}-\frac1{n(n+1)}
\end{array}
$$
then
$$
\sum_{k=0}^na_k=\frac1{n+1}+\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\right\rfloor}
$$